# $GET query to directory?

Tags: php, parameters, get, fetch

i want to fetch youtube videos from the above script but the above code is getting keyword from GET parameter example.com/s=keyword and i want it to get from a example.com/HERE
i mean you can see there is a `$_GET['s']`
So this function works like this

```
example.com/s=keyword
```

and i want it to work like this

```
example/page/keyword
```

sorry for my bad english

```
$keyword = $_GET['s'];
file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=$keyword&type=video&key=abcdefg&maxResults=5");
```

Comment: no you are not getting my problem i have url rewriting for my urls.

Comment: This link will help for apache url rewriting http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Then what exactly do you want to do? can you please explain further?

Comment: i want to fetch youtube videos from the above script but the above code is getting kewword from GET parameter example.com/s=keyword and i want it to get from a example.com/HERE.

Comment: example.com will be example.com, how can you rewrite the domain name itslef?. it should be `example.com/page/keyword`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
This will return you the current url. Then process it using simple string or array functions to get the params, like

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url_arr     = explode("/", $current_url);
```

Then access the parameters using the array indexes
like `$page = $url_arr[0];`